# unable to see status message after sending an email from contact page in html using php

Tags: php, html, html-email, email-attachments

I am trying to send an email from a contact page. the functionality is working fine, I am able to send mails from the html page but the only issue that I am facing is I am unable to see the Status div(success or failed).

Initially the page was redirecting to php file without any status message. I have added page redirect to the actual mailsend.html using header() in php. Now I want to have a status after the send operation whether mail has sent or not.

Below is the code snippet. Please help. Thanks in advance.

mailSend.html code:

```
<?php if(!empty($statusMsg)){ ?>
    <p class="statusMsg <?php echo !empty($msgClass)?$msgClass:''; ?>"><?php echo $statusMsg; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
<form action="example.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group">
       <input style = "padding-left:2%; width: 97%;" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Name" required="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input style = "padding-left:2%; width: 97%;" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Email address" required="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input style = "padding-left:2%; width: 97%;" type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Subject" required="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Write your message here" required="" style = 'border :0.5px solid '></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="file" name="attachment" class="form-control" style = 'border :0.5px solid; height: auto;'>
   </div>
   <div class="submit">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="SUBMIT" style= 'float : right;'>
   </div>
</form>
```

example.php code:

```
    <?php
                //first we leave this input field blank
                $recipient = "";
                //if user click the send button
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                    //access user entered data
                   $recipient = $_POST['email'];
                   $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                   $message = $_POST['message'];
                   $sender = "From: xyz@gmail.com";
                   //if user leave empty field among one of them
                   if(empty($recipient) || empty($subject) || empty($message)){
                       ?>
                       <!-- display an alert message if one of them field is empty -->
                        <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                            <?php echo "All inputs are required!" ?>
                        </div>
                       <?php
                    }else{
                        
                        $uploadStatus = 1;
        
                        // Upload attachment file
                        if(!empty($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])){
                            
                            // File path config
                            $targetDir = "uploads/";
                            $fileName = basename($_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);
                            $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
                            $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                            
                            // Allow certain file formats
                            $allowTypes = array('pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg');
                            if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
                                // Upload file to the server
                                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
                                    $uploadedFile = $targetFilePath;
                                }else{
                                    $uploadStatus = 0;
                                    $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                                }
                            }else{
                                $uploadStatus = 0;
                                $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only PDF, DOC, JPG, JPEG, & PNG files are allowed to upload.';
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if($uploadStatus == 1){
            
            // Recipient
            $toEmail = 'abc@gmail.com';

            // Sender
            $from = 'xyz@gmail.com';
            $fromName = 'example';
            
            // Subject
            $emailSubject = 'Contact Request Submitted by '.$recipient;
            
            // Message 
            $htmlContent = '<h2>Contact Request Submitted</h2>
                <p><b>Name:</b> '.$recipient.'</p>
                <p><b>Email:</b> '.$sender.'</p>
                <p><b>Subject:</b> '.$subject.'</p>
                <p><b>Message:</b><br/>'.$message.'</p>';
            
            // Header for sender info
            $headers = "From: $fromName"." <".$from.">";

            if(!empty($uploadedFile) && file_exists($uploadedFile)){
                
                // Boundary 
                $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
                $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 
                
                // Headers for attachment 
                $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 
                
                // Multipart boundary 
                $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n"; 
                
                // Preparing attachment
                if(is_file($uploadedFile)){
                    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                    $fp =    @fopen($uploadedFile,"rb");
                    $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($uploadedFile));
                    @fclose($fp);
                    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                    $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($uploadedFile)."\"\n" . 
                    "Content-Description: ".basename($uploadedFile)."\n" .
                    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($uploadedFile)."\"; size=".filesize($uploadedFile).";\n" . 
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
                }
                
                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
                $returnpath = "-f" . $recipient;
                
                // Send email
                $mail = mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);
                
                // Delete attachment file from the server
                @unlink($uploadedFile);
            }else{
                 // Set content-type header for sending HTML email
                $headers .= "\r\n". "MIME-Version: 1.0";
                $headers .= "\r\n". "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8";
                
                // Send email
                $mail = mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $htmlContent, $headers); 
            }
            
            // If mail sent
            if($mail){
                $statusMsg = 'Your contact request has been submitted successfully !';
                $msgClass = 'succdiv';
                ?>
                        <!-- display a success message if once mail sent sucessfully -->
                        <div class="alert alert-success text-center">
                            <!--<?php echo "Your mail successfully sent to $recipient"?>-->
                            <!--readfile('submitResume.html');-->
                            <?php 
                                header('Location: mailSend.html') ;
                                echo "Your mail successfully sent to $recipient"
                            ?>
                        </div>
                       <?php
                       $recipient = "";
                $postData = '';
            }else{
                $statusMsg = 'Your contact request submission failed, please try again.';
                 ?>
                        <!-- display an alert message if somehow mail can't be sent -->
                        <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                            <?php echo "Failed while sending your mail!" ?>
                        </div>
                       <?php
            }
            
        }    
       }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending to a .html page, which does not process PHP code by default, the server just serves it unless specifically configured on the server. Rename the page from `mailSend.html` to `mailSend.php` and it should resolve it. Make sure to change your code to send to .php page.

[For further reading see here](https://wpshout.com/learning-php-for-wordpress-development-how-to-include-php-in-html/)

You would need to pass the message itself or a way for the script to know which message to show. The easiest way would be to pass it via `$_GET`, by attaching it to the end of the URL you are trying to redirect. Like so:

```
$target_url = mailSend.php;
$get_data = '?statusMsg=' . urlencode($statusMsg) . '&$msgClass=' . urlencode($msgClass);
header( 'Location: ' . $target_url . $get_data );
```

Which you can then recover on `mailSend.php` via the global `$_GET` variable. Such as:

```
$statusMsg = urldecode($_GET['statusMsg']);
$msgClass= urldecode($_GET['msgClass']);
```

There are other ways to get the data from one page to another but that I will leave it up to you to do research. As it is out of scope for a simple answer.

Comment: Also the variable $statusMsg will not exist in the second page either, so you'll need to propose a way to resolve that as well

Comment: Well, ok, I will add that part too.